# Vertical align is not working

Tags: html, css

I have more than 3 child nodes and a single parent div. I want to align the `div` like a bricks. But the div is not positioning properly. The child's consuming unwanted space at bottom in between two div's.

Each child `div` have different heights, so `display: flex` property is not effective in the parent. Also tried with `column-count` property in the parent div and it's not working properly in chrome.

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/504/)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.small {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="small">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</div>
  <div class="small">It has survived not only five centuries.</div>
  <div class="small">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
  <div class="small">more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="small">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical.</div>
  <div class="small">Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</div>
  <div class="small">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make use of `flexbox`. Try it using https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I don't think this is possible with float at least if you want with fully dynamic way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS-Masonry` layout. See this link: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
.container{
  border: 1px black solid;  
  overflow: hidden;  
  vertical-align: top;
  display:flex;
}

.small{
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: aliceblue;
  align-self: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8g9cycs8/

Answer (score 0):

Please use flex box it will solve the problem very easily.

```
.Container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```